# is there a way to describe a kind of "keyfor" in typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-constraints, keyof

is there any way to express that a key-property for an object should be limited by related value? Something equivalent to keyof but for the value related to given key?

```
const objectAction = <T extends object>(obj: T): void => obj;
const onlyForObjects = <T extends object>(obj: T, key: keyof T): void =>
  objectAction(obj[key])
```

should work

```
onlyForObjects<{ a: number, b: object }>({ a: 0, b: {} }, 'b');
```

should not work

```
onlyForObjects<{ a: number, b: object }>({ a: 0, b: {} }, 'a');
```

Comment: are you saying, second parameter passed to `onlyForObjects` should accept only keys which holds object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then following is what you are after:

```js
type ObjKeys<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Record<any, any> ? P : never
}[keyof T]

const objectAction = <T>(obj: T): void => console.log(obj)

const onlyForObjects = <T>(obj: T, key: ObjKeys<T>): void => objectAction(obj[key])

onlyForObjects<{ a: number; b: Record<string, unknown> }>({ a: 0, b: {} }, 'b') // compiles
onlyForObjects<{ a: number; b: Record<string, unknown> }>({ a: 0, b: {} }, 'a') // does not compile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a generic [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) for type parameter `T`:

```
const onlyForObjects = <T extends Record<K, object>, K extends string>(
    obj: T, key: K): void => { }

onlyForObjects({ a: 0, b: {} }, 'b'); // works
onlyForObjects({ a: 0, b: {} }, 'a'); // error
```

Here is a  [live code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBOA2BPAYiATgeQEYCsCmwUEMAvDADwAqMeAHlHmACbEBKB6T5A0gDRy4CUAHz9uNeoxYxoaAJZgA5sIAUAKBiaBOAFwxK-ANZ5Ee7gEo9ANxBympYTADeMAL5q1CFOmz5CEFRcAQz0ABn4sPSdXN34Aciw48wBuTzAkVExBf0CYEJhwmEjnGNd4oKTkoA).

Comment: In this case, error is at first parameter and not at second. Which means, consumer of this function will not able to pass object with top level key and corresponding primitive value

Comment: If I do this `onlyForObjects({ a: 0, b: {}, c: 'foo' }, 'x')`, error I get is this (which is not what I think expected): 
error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'object'.
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'object'.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Look at the first sample line of the playground: `onlyForObjects({ a: 0, b: {}, c: "foo" }, 'b');`. Property `a` has a primitive value type - it works as intended.

Comment: You get error (when passed invalid second parameter), thats fine. But the error message which you get is misleading because of the implementation.

Comment: That is also working as intended. We shouldn't be able to select keys, that don't exist on the given object type (like `x`).

Comment: I know, it fails to compile but In my opinion, not the right way to do it.
With your impl - for this `onlyForObjects({ a: 0, b: {} }, 'a') `, error msg you get is `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'object'` this on first parameter

With my impl, error message you get is : `Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"b"'` this on second paramter

Comment: There are certainly a couple of ways to model this type. I see your concern, though could argue, your type might add abstraction cost and verbosity to a single function scoped problem. From my experience, it is a good idea to keep types as simple as possible, while still being complete/wholistic in the type checks. I think, this is just a trade-off between abstraction cost and DX and depends on the requirements at hand.

Comment: This seems more like a hack. Here `onlyForObjects({ a: 0, b: {} }, 'a') // error`, first parameter is completely valid, but because you have added type constraint saying that every key should have value of type object. I wont even read 2nd paramter in this case and try to figure out whats wrong with first. But the reality is, 2nd parameter is wrong and not the first.

Comment: hmm almost philosophical: do you have the wrong key for the right object or vice versa the wrong object for the right key? (-: Though you are right, it might be a bit more comprehensible, if the key would be listed first here.

Comment: If author says `{ a: 0, b: {} }` this is invalid object (irrespective of what second argument is) and should not be allowed to pass to `onlyForObjects`, then you are perfectly correct ;)

Comment: It is only invalid in `onlyForObjects`, as long as the key does not fit. I think, we won't fully agree on this point ;-). Anyway, thanks for the refreshing discussion (no sarcasm).

Comment: PS: changed  the constraint from `K extends keyof T` to `K extends string` in the case of unknown keys, which will emit a bit more clear error message as shown [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBOA2BPAYiATgeQEYCsCmwUEMAvDADwAqMeAHlHmACbEBKB6T5A0gDRy4CUAHz9uNeoxYxoaAJZgA5sIAUAKBiaBOAFwxK-ANZ5Ee7gEo9ANxBympYTADeMAL5qEKdNnyEIKlwBDPQAGfiw9J1c3fgAiWljzAG41IA).